# Eliminate variables and solve differential equations in a mixed nonlinear and linear equations

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear, control-systems

As another example of Eliminating some variables in a list of differential equations and solve them for specific defined variables, I consider to have some nonlinear equations plus some linear equations.

```
Solve[Eliminate[{a[t] == b1 + c*x1''[t], b2 == e*(x2[t] - y[t])
+ f*(x2'[t] - y'[t]) + d*x2''[t], g*y''[t] + e*(y[t] - x2[t])
+ f*(y'[t] - x2'[t]) + m*L == 0,
n*z''[t] == m - R, a1[t] == b3 + c1*alfa1''[t],
b4 - d1*L1*Sin[alfa2[t]] - n2*x3''[t]*L1*Sin[alfa2[t]] == r1*alfa2''[t],
d1 == M1*x4''[t], b1 == b2, y[t] == z[t]/L, 
y'[t] == z'[t]/L, y''[t] == z''[t]/L, x2[t] == x1[t],
x2'[t] == x1'[t], x2''[t] == x1''[t], alfa1[t] == alfa2[t], 
alfa1'[t] == alfa2'[t], alfa1''[t] == alfa2''[t], x3[t] == z[t], 
x3'[t] == z'[t], x3''[t] == z''[t],
x4[t] == x3[t] - L*Cos[alfa2[t]], x4'[t] == x3'[t] + L1*alfa2'[t]*Sin[alfa2[t]], x4''[t] == x3''[t] + L1*alfa2''[t]*Sin [alfa2[t]] + 
 L1*(alfa2'[t])^2*Cos[alfa2[t]],
b3 == b4}, {b1, b2, x2[t], x2'[t], x2''[t], y[t],
y'[t], y''[t], m, x3[t], d1, b3, b4, x3'[t],
x3''[t], alfa2[t], alfa2'[t], alfa2''[t], x4[t], x4'[t], 
x4''[t]}], {x1''[t], z''[t], alfa1''[t]}]
```

Mathematica complains when I am including the nonlinear part

```
Eliminate::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Eliminate, so some
solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>
Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables. >>
```

and it just give an answer of

```
{{x1''[t] -> -((-L a[t] + e L x1[t] - e z[t] + f L x1'[t] -
  f z'[t])/((c + d) L)), z''[t] -> -((L^2 R - e L x1[t] + e z[t] -
f L x1'[t] +f z'[t])/(g + L^2 n))}}
```

and there is no answer for `alfa1''[t]`, I am wondering is that because of using `Sin[]` and `Cos[]`? Is it possible for Mathematica to recognize `Sin^(-1)` as `ArcSin` in complicated equations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Eliminate` seems to be able to handle some simple equations with transcendental functions, like `Sin`, but sometimes it will not work with them, as you can see in the following minimal examples

```
Eliminate[{y == z, x + Sin[y] == 5}, y]
Eliminate[{x + Cos[y]*Sin[y] == 5, y == z}, y]
```

[image]

For your specific case, I am going to leave the elimination of `alfa2` out (I commented it out in the following code)

```
el = Eliminate[
    {
     a[t] == b1 + c*x1''[t]
     , b2 == e*(x2[t] - y[t]) + f*(x2'[t] - y'[t]) + d*x2''[t]
     , g*y''[t] + e*(y[t] - x2[t]) + f*(y'[t] - x2'[t]) + m*L == 0
     , n*z''[t] == m - R
     , a1[t] == b3 + c1*alfa1''[t]
     , b4 - d1*L1*Sin[alfa2[t]] - n2*x3''[t]*L1*Sin[alfa2[t]] == 
      r1*alfa2''[t]
     , d1 == M1*x4''[t]
     , b1 == b2
     , y[t] == z[t]/L
     , y'[t] == z'[t]/L
     , y''[t] == z''[t]/L
     , x2[t] == x1[t]
     , x2'[t] == x1'[t]
     , x2''[t] == x1''[t]
     , alfa1[t] == alfa2[t]
     , alfa1'[t] == alfa2'[t]
     , alfa1''[t] == alfa2''[t], x3[t] == z[t]
     , x3'[t] == z'[t]
     , x3''[t] == z''[t]
     , x4[t] == x3[t] - L*Cos[alfa2[t]]
     , x4'[t] == x3'[t] + L1*alfa2'[t]*Sin[alfa2[t]]
     , x4''[t] == 
      x3''[t] + L1*alfa2''[t]*Sin[alfa2[t]] + 
       L1*(alfa2'[t])^2*Cos[alfa2[t]]
     , b3 == b4
     }
    , {
     b1
     , b2
     , x2[t], x2'[t], x2''[t]
     , y[t], y'[t], y''[t]
     , m
     , x3[t]
     , d1, b3, b4
     , x3'[t], x3''[t]
     (*,alfa2[t],alfa2'[t],alfa2''[t]*)
     , x4[t], x4'[t], x4''[t]
     }
    ] // FullSimplify;
Do[Print[{i, el[[i]]}], {i, Length@el}]
```

[image]

The second equation is your non-linear equation with the transcendental functions. Mathematica is not able to handle them, as far as I have tried only with `Eliminate[el[[2 ;; 3]], alfa2[t]]`. But what you can do in your specific example is replace `alfa2` with `alfa1`

```
elnew = el /. alfa2 -> alfa1;
Do[Print[{i, elnew[[i]]}], {i, Length@elnew}]
```

[image]

and solve for the variables you are interested in

```
sol = First@Solve[elnew, {x1''[t], z''[t], alfa1''[t]}]
```

[image]

**EDIT**

In the documentation, it  is written that `Eliminate` works mainly with polynomial equations and may be able to handle simple transcendental functions

[image]

[image]

but as you could see in my second example at the beginning of this answer, it might fail for more complex equations. You can try to turn on the option `InverseFunctions` (see options of `Eliminate`) but this will not help you in your specific case. You have a product of `Sin` and `Cos` in your non-linear part. Consider the following code

```
eqs1 = {
   a1[t] == Sin[y[t]]*Cos[y[t]]
   , y[t] == z[t]
   };
eqs2 = {
   a[t] == x'[t]
   , a1[t] == Sin[y[t]]*Cos[y[t]]
   , y[t] == z[t]
   };
Eliminate[eqs1, y[t]]
Eliminate[eqs2, y[t]]
Eliminate[eqs2, y[t], InverseFunctions -> True]
Eliminate[eqs2, y[t], InverseFunctions -> False]
```

[image]

In the first output you can see that `Eliminate` is not able to handle the complex equations `eqs1` since it can not eliminate `y[t]`. In the second output you can notice that `Eliminate` actually **ignores** everything it can not handle, but gives you a warning. In the third output I told it to use inverse functions but as it is not able to handle it, it still seems to ignore it. In the fourth output, it gives you nothing.

So bottom line from my side, it seems like `Eliminate` will ignore everything it can not handle by prefering polynomial expressions.

*Note:* I don't think this is a bug, but a property of `Eliminate` by working on polynomial expressions. If something is not expressable as a polynomial, then it just can not be done. I don't know how difficult it is to expand the functionalities of `Eliminate` to more complex functions, but that is something you would have to ask a mathematician and people from Wolfram.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that I cannot break down the code to few lines, and solve linear and nonlinear equations separately, I am sending all equations from matlab to mathematica, so I should be able to eliminate and solve all equations in one line coding. @Mauricio Lobos

Comment: yea, ok I guess one line coding would be this way:

First@Solve[(Eliminate[equation, elims] // FullSimplify) /. 
   alfa2 -> alfa1, {x1''[t], z''[t], alfa1''[t]}]

Comment: but, it would be nice to know the reason of not getting result by including alfa2 and its derivatives as elimination @Mauricio Lobos

Comment: @FaribaRahimi seems like `Eliminate` ignores equations it can not handle, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the complete response, yes you are right, in a complicated equations it again fails to give a correct answer.  @Mauricio Lobos

Comment: The hidden syntax of `Solve` together with `MaxExtraConditions` helps in this case, try `Solve[{y == z, x + Sin[y] == 5}, x, {y}, MaxExtraConditions -> Infinity]`
`Solve[{x + Cos[y]*Sin[y] == 5, y == z}, x, {y}, MaxExtraConditions -> Infinity]`

`Solve[eqs1, {a1[t]}, {y[t]}, MaxExtraConditions -> Infinity]`

`Solve[eqs2, {a1[t], x'[t]}, {y[t]}, MaxExtraConditions -> Infinity]`

Comment: `Method -> Reduce` also helps: `Solve[{y == z, x + Sin[y] == 5}, x, {y}, Method -> Reduce]`